# Is there a way to view same column result in the same column of different rows after doing Group by?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to calculate the sum of one column but with different dates.
So if it's today date it should calculate the sum of today's amount. I have done this.

The issue is Today Column shows the data if only the row has the date matched with the other referencedate column.
I want to view the Today Column Data in all the Columns regardless of any date or row with any referencedate column. 
Example
This is what I am getting:

```
ReferenceDate  Item  Amount  Today    Yesterday   Accordingtodate
03/29/2019       1    100     100         0             100
03/28/2019       1     80       0        80              80
03/27/2019       1     50       0         0              50
```

I have put cases in my query like this:

```
IsNull(Case When ReferenceDate = '03/29/2019' Then Sum(Fact_dayclosingsales.Qty) End,0)  As Today, \\ For Today
IsNull(Case When ReferenceDate = '03/28/2019' Then Sum(Fact_dayclosingsales.Qty) End,0)  As Yesterday, \\For Yesterday
```

This is what I want:

```
Date         Item    Amount     Today    Yesterday    Accordingtodate
03/29/2019     1      100        100        80            100
03/28/2019     1       80        100        80             80
03/27/2019     1       50        100        80             50
```

Today and Yesterday should show same data in every row regardless of any date like the above table.

The database was created in 2002 with SQL SERVER 2000 and i am using SQL SERVER 2017 to manage it. Some functions and queries will not work.

My main task is to just show sales and amount according to the column name in the table. Like Today, Yesterday, LastMonthSameDate and many more. Above given tables are just an example of what i want to do.

Answer (score 1):

We can try pivoting using `MAX` as an analytic function:

```
SELECT
    Date,
    Amount,
    MAX(CASE WHEN ReferenceDate = '03/29/2019'
             THEN Qty END) OVER () AS Today,
    MAX(CASE WHEN ReferenceDate = '03/23/2019'
             THEN Qty END) OVER () AS Yesterday,
    Accordingtodate
FROM Fact_dayclosingsales
ORDER BY
    Date;
```

If you are using a really old version of SQL Server which does not support analytic functions, then we can try using subqueries instead:

```
SELECT
    Date,
    Amount,
    (SELECT Qty FROM Fact_dayclosingsales
     WHERE ReferenceDate = '03/29/2019') AS Today,
    (SELECT Qty FROM Fact_dayclosingsales
     WHERE ReferenceDate = '03/28/2019') AS Yesterday,
    Accordingtodate
FROM Fact_dayclosingsales
ORDER BY
    Date;
```

Comment: I tried using Over () but it gives an error ' Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'OVER'.
'. I think it's because i am using  sql server 2000( The table base) and i am currently using Sql server 2017. Over is not supported in sql server 2000.

Comment: Please edit your question and show clean input and output, and _make sure_ that the column names match your query.